# Why do jobs in slurm freeze indefinitely when they are TensorFlow scripts?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, slurm

I am having this error when I use the slurm (http://slurm.schedmd.com/) workload manager. When I run some tensorflow python scripts, sometimes it results in an error (attached). It seems that it can't find cuda library installed but I am running scripts that do not require GPUs. Therefore, I find it very confusing why cuda would be an issue at all. Why is cuda installation an issue if I don't need it?

The only useful information I got from the slurm-job_id file was the following:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:102] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /cm/shared/openmind/cuda/7.5/lib64:/cm/shared/openmind/cuda/7.5/lib
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:2092] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:491] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:153] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: node047
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:160] hostname: node047
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:185] libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:347] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  352.63  Sat Nov  7 21:25:42 PST 2015
GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
"""
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] kernel reported version is: 352.63.0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:81] No GPU devices available on machine.
```

I always thought that tensorflow would not require GPU. So I am assuming the last error saying there is not GPU is NOT causing the error (correct me if I am wrong).

**I dont understand why I need the CUDA library. I am trying to run my jobs with GPU, why would I need the cuda library if my jobs are CPU jobs?**

---

I tried logging into the node directly and starting tensorflow but I got no apparent error:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:102] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /cm/shared/openmind/cuda/7.5/lib64:/cm/shared/openmind/cuda/7.5/lib
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:2092] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

though I expected the error:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:102] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /cm/shared/openmind/cuda/7.5/lib64:/cm/shared/openmind/cuda/7.5/lib
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:2092] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:491] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:153] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: node047
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:160] hostname: node047
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:185] libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:347] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  352.63  Sat Nov  7 21:25:42 PST 2015
GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
"""
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] kernel reported version is: 352.63.0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:81] No GPU devices available on machine.
```

---

I also made an official git issue in the tensorflow library:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3632

Comment: Answering the question "Why might it be?": tensorflow from within slurm environment can't find libcuda.so: `libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so`

Comment: @RobertCrovella so the error is not due to `libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so` I always thought if it couldn't find a GPU it wouldn't use it and it wouldn't matter.

Comment: made an official git issue to see if someone can help me with this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3632

Comment: @RobertCrovella that message is purely informational:

TensorFlow has separate builds for CPU and GPU binaries (http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/) You seem to be running a GPU build on a machine that has no GPUs, hence the warning. However, it should still work regardless, this message is purely informational.

quoting yaroslavvb from google and tensorflow.

Comment: How do you know it's stalling? Maybe it's busy working and just takes longer than you expect. A lot of stalling issues have to do with improper usage of queues, so try running some examples that don't use queues or input pipelines

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov You are right in some respect. It might be busy, though I have no idea whats busy with. However, I have my NN (main.py) to print error statistics every 50 iterations. In fact, before it even runs anything, it should be printing stuff. In my local computer with the same parameters it prints statistics and other stuff pretty much immediately. It takes time to go from 50 to another 50 iterations. But in slurm, it writes to a slurm file where I can track its progress. The runs that get "stuck" don't write anything besides the tf errors that I posted in the question.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I have not tracked the pattern, but the jobs that do run, print the expected statistics I expect during training. I can actually track their training as they run. But not all get stuck. I don't understand why it would pause and then run my job (if its even doing that...)

Comment: You can easily cause deadlocks if you are using queues improperly, I think you need to isolate the issue further -- add logging to figure out at what point they get stuck, and initialize all sessions with `sess = tf.Session(
      config=tf.ConfigProto(session_timeout_in_ms=10000))` to help with deadlocks

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov sorry if this is a dum question. But what do you mean by logging? My script is already writing to files I can inspect during execution, if I wanted.

I was inspecting on which nodes my jobs are running and sometimes two jobs run in same computer. Can that cause deadlocks?

Comment: By logging I mean adding enough print statements to figure out at which point the job gets stuck. I dunno about slurm, but TensorFlow cpu can do multiple processes in parallel

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov the script that I am sending to be executed has a block of import statements and after that block the first thing is a print statement. It seems its not even reaching the first print/log statement in my script (before it does any real work). I might try putting a print statement before the import block and right after and see what happens. Btw, thanks for your help and patience so far :)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Just to add more information to the discussion, in slurm one can explicitly say to assign jobs to nodes with GPU's. I've observed that the apparent "stalling" only happens when jobs are sent to machine that are suppose to be CPU only.

If the machine is artificially restricted to only use CPU but tensorflow detects GPUs, can tensorflow accidentally get stuck?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov not sure if its possible, but is it possible to have tensorflow deadlock the OS? I observed that when it was either writing a model or file renaming.

Answer (score 1):

There is some bug in tensorflow operating with slurm submitting via a batch job.

Currently I get around it by running srun on slurm.

It also appears in your case that you installed the GPU version of tensorflow and are running it on a machine that does not have a GPU. Which is causing another error in your case.

Comment: what do you mean that you are running srun? Do you mind clarifying that? Unfortunately, I require to run about 30 scripts at once, which srun doesn't do. I guess I am stuck with sbatch with GPU (that does get stuck but less so).

Comment: "srun --pty bash"  will give you an interactive session.  When they fix it or I find out the reason behind it I'll post it up but all I know is that there's a bug with submitting sbatch jobs.

Comment: so when you run srun and bash, u then run the jobs and everything runs as expected? (Just as an update, it seems it gets stuck on GPUs too sometimes)

Comment: have you found any way to run multiple jobs at once with slurm right now even with this weird problem?

Comment: have you experienced this issue even with tensorflow 0.10.0?

Comment: I will be testing it again probably today and post up if its fixed in 0.10

Comment: Steven, do you still have this stalling issue to? Or can you be more detailed of what type of issue you have? I recently after some tedious and painful debugging yesterday, seems to me that the sbatch script was not flushing everything to the slurm-ID.out log file unitl I explicitly told it in python to flush. Maybe it was queuing IO writes or something. I'm still yet to do more testing to confirm this however, it seems that was part of the issue. Just want to confirm you had the same issue or what the nature of your problem was/is.

Comment: It's now fixed when I'm using 0.10.  Yeah I'm not sure what my previous issue was to be honest.  did you ever try to end your tensorflow program early to see if it saved?  I'm not sure how you're slurm is configured where you're set up.

Comment: I was checkpointing my tensorflow models and once I stopped doing that the stalling issue stopped. Not sure if that was it but it might be some way locking works with tensorflow interferes with slurm.

Comment: How are you checkpointing them?  I've been able to check point okay now on slurm.

Comment: using: `save_path = saver.save(sess, path+mdl_dir+'/model.ckpt',global_step=i)` how are you doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar issue, and I managed to boil it down to the saver hanging when writing the model to the lustre file system. Still waiting on a real solution though.